# How to pull remote Git master if it doesn't exist locally?

Tags: git, git-branch

I created a Git "newfeature" branch on my laptop, implemented a new feature, and then merged newfeature into my master branch.  As I was working on the new feature, I had also created and pulled this newfeature branch on my production server in order to test it there.  Now that I'm done with this branch, I'd like to get rid of it on my production server and pull my updated master branch down into production.  How exactly do I do this?

Here's what I see on my production server:

```
% git branch
* newfeature
% git ls-remote
4f533....  HEAD
4f533....  refs/head/master
4f533....  refs/head/newfeature
```

If I try to pull master down, I see this:

```
% git pull origin master
* branch      master    -> FETCH_HEAD
```

I tried to make HEAD point to master but that doesn't work:

```
% git update-ref HEAD master
fatal: master: not a valid SHA1
```

How do I replace this "newfeature" branch on my production server with my newly-updated master branch if master doesn't already exist on the server?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `git update-ref` directly, that's a very low level command meant for writing scripts that are (or become) part of git itself.  Do use `git checkout` to switch from one branch to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull the `master` branch to the server as you already did. Then, if it is same as `newfeature`, just checkout `master` and remove `newfeature`:

```
git pull origin master
git checkout master
git branch -D newfeature
```